# AVPictureinPictureController - Can I pause pipController multiple times?

Tags: ios, swift, pip, avplayer, picture-in-picture

I'm using `Picture in Picture(PiP)` feature in my application using `AVPictureInPictureController` and it's delegate methods.
I want to call `saveClipfunc()` multiple times when click pause icon of `AVPictureInPictureController` each time.
But play/pause icon is changed to larger rectangle icon when click once and after that, is not changed again (remains larger rectangle icon).

[before click play/pause](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfL95.jpg)

[after click play/pause](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndP0o.jpg)

```swift
    func pictureInPictureController(_ pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController, setPlaying playing: Bool) {
        if !playing {
                saveClipfunc()
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
```

this is delegate methods of `AVPictureInPictureSampleBufferPlaybackDelegate`. when paused, call `saveClipfunc()`.
So Can I pause `pipController` multiple times?

Comment: What do `saveClipfunc`?

Comment: That's function what i want to call when click pause. saveClipfunc() saves clip what I want. that's not important point. The main point is to pause multiple times. So did you see before and after play/pause icon image i've uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Better approach would be propably observing **if**  `AVPlayer` **is paused and if PiP is simultaneously active**. Here is an example:

Here are yor class variables, you propably initialize `AVPlayer` and `AVPictureInPictureController` somewhere on different place in your code, so take it just as an example:

```
var playerRateObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
var pictureInPictureController = AVPictureInPictureController()
var avPlayer = AVPlayer()
```

Somewhere in your code assign observer to `playerRateObserver`  variable:

```
let playerRateObserver = avPlayer.observe(\.rate, options: [.new, .initial], changeHandler: {(player, rate) in
    if rate.newValue == 1 {
        //"user pressed play"
    }
    if rate.newValue == 0 {
        //user pressed stop
        if pictureInPictureController.isPictureInPictureActive {
            saveClipfunc()
        }
    }
})
```

Do not forget to deinitialize your observer at the end of you class / struct by adding `deinit` function:

```
deinit {
    playerRateObserver?.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: How can I use playerRateObserver variable? sorry for missing. That method is delegate of AVPictureInPictureSampleBufferPlaybackDelegate ! and what is avPlayer? is it player of PIP?

Comment: I added some more explanation in my original answer by editing it. And yes, `avPlayer` is the player that `AVPictureInPictureController` uses.

Comment: let avPlayer = pipController.playerLayer.player var pipController = AVPictureInPictureController() pipController = AVPictureInPictureController(
                contentSource: .init(
                    sampleBufferDisplayLayer:
                        bufferDisplayLayer,
                    playbackDelegate: self)) WHERE CAN I IMPLEMENT let playerRateObserver = avPlayer.observe(\.rate, options: [.new, .initial], changeHandler: {(player, rate) in
    if rate.newValue == 0 {
        if pictureInPictureController.isPictureInPictureActive {
            saveClipfunc()
        }
    }
})

Comment: I've just tried to implement your code. but when pause pipcontroller, saveClipfunc() function was not called. what's problem?

Comment: Check if you implemented it properly and try to debug.  You can insert couple print statements there and check if code inside your observer is triggering when user stops the player (regardless of PiP active or not). You can temporarily remove the `if pictureInPictureController.isPictureInPictureActive` condition

Comment: did you manage to solve the issue ?

Comment: I've tried again but no changes. it didn't fix!